# AndroidStudio JUnit printing new line in log after each @Test

Tags: unit-testing, android-studio, junit, junit4

After updating to latest Android Studio version (3.6.1), JUnit logs changed a bit.

One of the things I recently noticed is that every new Test the log is adding a couple of new empty lines to the test log.

This becomes increasingly bad in our project that has thousands of tests, as it becomes difficult to see if any UT sent a crash log but assertion resulted ok.

Any known way to deactivate this behavior?

Added lines:
[image: Added lines]

Reduced lines:
[image: Reduced lines]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NVM it is fixed in the newest Android Studio 4.0